# gzip in cython file

Tags: gzip, cython

I am using cython to parsing large gzipped files. Is there any recommended way to use the gzip library as a file buffer to getline?  The readline from gzip in Python takes well too long.

I would like to do this:

```
 gzip_file = gzip.open(file_name, ¨rb¨)

 getline(line,n, gzip_file)
```

Comment: The prevailing wisdom (from a quick google search) suggests that the quickest way to read gzip files in Python is by calling `zcat` from a subprocess (it needs to be installed on your system though). You may also get significant benefits from wrapping the `gzip_file` in an `io.BufferedReader` and using `readline` from that.

Comment: thank you,  this was a  good suggestion that lead to my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution I found  was using mkfifo and processing that with c++ libraries.

```
os.mkfifo(file_name)
subprocess.Popen("gunzip -c file.gz >" +  file_name)
cython.process(file_name)
```

Comment: I misspoke, I use boost and c++11 for almost everything c++.